# Expected behavior from modifications of Collections and Arrays in-place during "for each" statement

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, collections

I am curious about the following behavior. I am mainly concerned about the behavior of a Collection object. I am currently working on a code that reads a lot of data into collections. These collections then needs to be "washed" from incompatible data with a lot of loops and controls. If a collection item is incompatible it should be removed from the collection (and references to this data needs to be updated). Is it safe to use "for each" loops to modify the collections. From the code below I can see that I get the intended behavior, but is this behavior documented and will it always work in future updates of vba?

I also included examples from two types of arrays as I find it interesting to know that updating an array item is also compatible with the "for each" loop, but resizing an dynamic array is not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ModifyInPlace()
    Dim myCollection As Collection, myArray1 As Variant, myArray2(5) As String, item As Variant
    Dim sOutput As String
    
    Set myCollection = New Collection
    With myCollection
        .Add "A"
        .Add "B"
        .Add "C"
        .Add "D"
        .Add "E"
        .Add "F"
    End With
    sOutput = sOutput & "Collection items cycled: "
    For Each item In myCollection
        sOutput = sOutput & item & ", "
        If item = "B" Then myCollection.Remove 4    'Removes "D"
        If item = "C" Then myCollection.Add "G"     'Adds "G"
    Next
    
    myArray1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    sOutput = sOutput & vbCrLf & "Array1 items cycled:     "
    For Each item In myArray1
        sOutput = sOutput & item & ", "
        'If item = "B" Then ReDim myArray1(4)       'Removes "F" - this statement throws an Run-time error '10'
                                                    '              "This array is fixed or temporarily locked"
        If item = "D" Then myArray1(4) = "!"        'Modfies "E"
    Next
    
    myArray2(0) = "A"
    myArray2(1) = "B"
    myArray2(2) = "C"
    myArray2(3) = "D"
    myArray2(4) = "E"
    myArray2(5) = "F"
    sOutput = sOutput & vbCrLf & "Array2 items cycled:     "
    For Each item In myArray2
        sOutput = sOutput & item & ", "
        If item = "D" Then myArray2(4) = "!"        'Modfies "E"
    Next
    
    Debug.Print sOutput
End Sub
```

The output on my machine is this:

- Collection items cycled: A, B, C, E, F, G,
- Array1 items cycled:     A, B, C, D, !, F,
- Array2 items cycled:     A, B, C, D, !, F,

Comment: IMO you can use `for-each` to modify the `VBA.Collection` object because it is kind of a `Set` which (as I guess) contains internaly another structures for storing `keys` and corresponding `values`. So the `for-each` which gets the `enumarator` of collection will use the internal structures and try to access them. Importatnt is that if index doesn't match an existing member of the collection, an error occurs. With arrays it is different because the `for-each` gets an `enumerator` object which uses the array itself directly so it can't be modified when in use. But I am not aware of any docu :(.